# Change default Xamarin Studio's web server

Tags: macos, nginx, xamarin, mod-mono, xamarin-studio

Is it possible to change Xamarin Studio's web server from XPS to another like Nginx or Apache with mod_mono?

I did not find any option that looks like the one Visual Studio has where you have the ability to point to any kind of web server:

[image]

I'm on Mac OS X lion 10.7.3

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?